# React UseForm: How to ignore form validation using "Save as Draft"

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, use-form

I am working on one project in React and for the form validation, I've been using UseForm. I have two buttons at the end of the form "Save as Draft" and "Send". If you click on both buttons it will submit the form only if all required fields are filled - meaning validation has been successful.

But I would like to bypass that validation when you click on "Save as Draft" button and ignore that form validation.

Is that possible using useForm or should I change my validation and use something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to use submit if you are not really submitting? What's wrong with normal button?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski sorry if I wasn't clear enough, but even if you click on "Save as Draft" button it will be submitted to the database as even (filled 10%, 50% or empty form) but with "Save & Send" everything needs to be filled in order to submit it to DB. https://prnt.sc/aywNnzVmqx7s

Comment: Don't use submit event, use click event

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Thank you very much! The solution was so easy that I'm laughing right now. Thank you one more time! :) It works just as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented it with zod validation:

```
export const draftResolver = zodResolver<zod.ZodType<Partial<YourPayloadType>>>(
    zod.object({
        id: zod.string({
            required_error: 'id is required',
        }),
    }),
);

export const defaultResolver = zodResolver<zod.ZodType<YourPayloadType>>(
...

// Inside a component
const isDraft = React.useRef(false);

const methods = useForm({
    resolver: (...args) => {
        if (isDraft.current) {
            return draftResolver(...args);
        }
        return defaultResolver(...args);
    },
    defaultValues,
});

const onSubmit = (draft?: boolean) => {
    isDraft.current = Boolean(draft);

    methods.handleSubmit(async (data) => {
        // any logic you want to submit the form
    })();
};
```